# Block WireGuard clients' access to specific websites

Tags: firewalls, access-control, openvpn, wireguard

I have installed a WireGuard VPN server on a Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian) using [PiVPN](https://www.pivpn.io/) and I would like to

1. either block the VPN clients to access specific websites (i.e. block them access https://www.foo.com and https://www.bar.com) or
2. let them access them by using their IP and not the Raspberry's.

Furthermore, I am also using the UFW Firewall.

Is there a way to achieve that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are the websites in question behind Cloudflare? If so, then this is impossible without either getting your clients to accept a rogue root CA and spying on all of their connections, or blocking everything that's behind Cloudflare (which is a very large portion of the Internet).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware if they are behind Cloudflare. Let's say that we are certain that https://www.foo.com is not behind Cloudflare. How can I block the access to it?

Answer (score 2):

I see three ways this could be implemented, but no real "perfect" solution. Here are your options:

1. Drop requests to these sites at firewall level. This means you have
   to block the IPs of these websites, which might be doable for small
   sites (with a single IP and no LB or reverse proxy) but very hard /
   impossible for big sites. Also you'll have to block all Cloudflare's
   site if one of them is it the list... Not a very good option but
   once the IPs are blocked in the firewall you know for sure no one
   will reach them.
2. Implement you own DNS server and blacklist the domain names. Since you said you are using a Raspberry, you could look into PiHole which is a DNS server for Raspberry. You'll then have to configure clients to use the Raspberry as their DNS server. This is easier to implement than the first one but it can be bypassed by changing DNS server in Wiregard option for the client.
3. Redirect all VPN requests through a proxy doing some SSL inspection. VPN clients will have to install the proxy's CA on their device and then you can do some blacklisting on the "Host" header for example.